# How do I apply scale to an armature while keeping the deforms on amesh that has shape keys?

Tags: rigging, shape-keys

So a bit of background as to what I want to do:

I'm trying to create a single mesh which is parented to an armature for use with different characters.  Rather than building a character model from the ground up each time, I want to build a sort of universal mesh that I can use for different characters.  That mesh would have a bunch of shape keys for things like phonemes and the sort.  The mesh is then rigged to an armature, including bones for things like the lips, jaw, etc...

Now, what I want is to use that mesh+rig for different characters.  So, if I want a tall character, I would scale some bones up, fix proportions, etc...  The mesh would also be adjusted to make the character thinner, fatter, more muscular, etc...

For the face, I plan on making a new shape key and then editing/sculpting the mesh to look how I want.  As it's based on the same original mesh, in theory all my phoneme shape keys should still work reasonably well with only minimal tweaking.

My problem though, is that if I scale the armature around, it makes rigging new things like clothes, shoes, etc...  quite difficult.  So, how do I apply scale to the armature, while also applying those deformations to the mesh?  Right now, I can't just apply the armature, as Blender tells me it can't be done to an object that has shape keys.

Thanks in advance for any answers, and apologies if I'm not asking quite as properly as I should, I fairly new to BSE.